# How do I can close/hide a frame based upon a button click event in wpf?

Tags: wpf, button, click, frame

I have two frames I need to a load the second frame based on the button click event which is there in the first frame, and need to hide the first frame once the second frame is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you Navigate simply?
you can use `NavigationService.Navigate()` on button click event and navigate inside the same frame, you don't need a separate frame then. Do you have any specific requirement that you are using 2 different frames?

Comment: yes, both are two different frames. one is just a login frame this will load the main frame which represent my system functions. once the user verified via the login frame he will get into the main frame then the login frame will disappear.. 

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks .